# Edited comment doesn't update display immediately

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

Someone commented on my answer and I just replied to that in a comment. The I immediately edited the comment by selecting it and then pressing edit on action bar.

The edit didn't show up, even after doing a pull to refresh on the question, it was showing the comment in its original form.

It only showed up once I reopened the question from the right drawer (notifications).

The apps says 1.0.60 in about.

Comment: Reproduced, when editing again you do get the correct contents though.

Comment: When I edited the second time the editor contained the correct comment, but the display didn't.

Comment: When I scroll past the top of the question to reload the question, the comment retains the stale data. But if I go to the recent notifications menu and open the recent notification through there, it actually reloads the comment. Perhaps comments should be reloaded when reloading the question (as a separate issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed as of any version greater than 1.0.81, 1.0.82 should be hitting [the beta tier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app) in the next few hours. This was a caching issue, but it was a really convoluted caching issue.

The same fix also fixed the related bug of comment contents not updating after a pull to refresh.

Comment: Confirmed in 1.0.82 beta.