# In the Android app, my edits aren't visible

Tags: bug, edits, android-app

When I edit a question or my own comments in the app, after asking to submit the edit I get shown the original, unedited text.

This is version 1.0.77 (updated 24 nov 2015) on Samsung Galaxy 6 Edge, everything up to date as of today.

Comment: Comments are known long time bug, reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252949/edited-comment-doesnt-update-display-immediately). As for question edit, didn't notice, you sure about that?

Comment: @ShadowWizard that was how I noticed it in the first place

Comment: It certainly applies to *suggested edits*, which is irritating and contrary to the behaviour of the browser interface.